# How to find the average of each cell in multiple csv's

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, csv

I have several excel files with data in them in a format similar to this

```
csv1             csv1
  a b c           a b c
x 1 2 3         x 3 2 1
y 4 5 6         y 6 5 4
```

There are 3 csv's total, and I need to create a new csv with the average of each cell.
So `csv3` would be as follows

```
  a       b        c
x (3+1)/2) (2+2)/2  (3+1)/2
y (6+4)/2  etc.
```

So far I have the files imported but I am not sure how to proceed.

```
import pandas as pd

def Averager(fileA,fileB,fileC):
    csvA=pd.read_csv(fileA)
    csvB=pd.read_csv(fileB)
    csvC=pd.read_csv(fileC)
    g=pd.concat([csvA, csvB, csvC]).groupby(level=0).mean()
    print(g)                                                   
print(Averager('a.csv','b.csv','c.csv'))
```

Comment: You mention you have an Excel workbook, then you mention you have csvs - which is it?  You can import an Excel workbook with `openpyxl` and `pandas` so you don't need the intermediate csvs, FYI.

Comment: What about `df1.add(df2)/2`.  Or, in your case: `(csvA+csvB+csvC)/3` - providing all DataFrames are of the same shape, as in the example shown.

Comment: Thank you @S3DEV, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged `numpy`, I'm assuming a numpy solution would work.

```
import numpy as np
csv1 = np.genfromtxt('my_file1.csv', delimiter=',')
csv2 = np.genfromtxt('my_file2.csv', delimiter=',')
np.savetxt("foo.csv", (csv1+csv2)/2, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thank you Kung Fu Panda!

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close, here is a solution that should work. I use pathlib to create the filenames, it's pretty easy to use.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(r"path/to/file")

data = {}
for i in range(1,4):
    f = p / f"csv{i}.csv"
    data[i]=pd.read_csv(f)

df = pd.concat(data)
avg=df.groupby(level=1).mean()

print(df)
print(avg)
```

Comment: Recommend using `os.path.join` and string formatting over this `p / ("csv"+str(i)+".csv")`, as it's very un-Pythonic.

Comment: @S3DEV No, that is the old way pre-`pathlib`.  Though I do disagree with their choice of string concat: `p / f"csv{i}.csv"`

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley - Point taken.  In that case, the `pathlib` syntax is horrible.  In my head `/` is a division operator.  Ick.

Comment: @S3DEV It looks nicer when you have multiple path fragments: `p / "root" / "files" / "etc"`

Comment: @S3DEV - it took me a while to get used to it, but now I only use pathlib, I really started to like the idea of using "/" to concatenate paths.

Answer (score 0):

One super simple approach, after reading the CSV data into DataFrames is:

```
 df1.add(df2)/2
```

Or, in this specific case:

```
(csvA+csvB+csvC)/3
```

This works, providing all DataFrames are of the same shape, (and numeric) as shown in the original example.